# javascript not loading asynchronously

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling

I have just realized a major slowdown in my app.  I use modal dialogs to load other pages of my site into a pop up.  Up until recently these loaded very fast.  Lately they are taking a vary long time, about 4 seconds.  I did some profiling and it seems that my javascript isn't loading asynchronously, each one waits until the other has completed downloading.

[image]

This seems to be the major slow down.  Each javascript file is just included in the loaded page like so...

```
<script src="/js/jquery.ae.image.resize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="/js/entry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
```

I sort of fixed this by moving these files to the page showing the dialogs, but that seems like a hack, especially when they were loading fast enough in the past.  Also, this isn't dynamic javascript so it can be cached, I think the time parameters come from `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` but that isn't a recent code addition.

Comment: something in your code is probably preventing the fetching of files from cache by adding `?_xxxxxx` in js files request. You should address it.

Comment: I believe that is from $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); but that is not new code.  Could a new version of jQuery handle that differently?

Comment: one solution could be is to load the scripts from different domain names

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load scripts asynchronously, **async** attribute helps:

```
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src ="/js/entry.js"></script>
```

Comment: this doesn't help it seems async is for execution not loading of scripts.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async " Each async script executes at the first opportunity after it is finished downloading and before the window’s load event. "